# How can I navigate back to LoginScreen from ProfileScreen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Here is Code for the reference
I have 3 navgraphs
one for rootNavs and 2nd one for authentication and 3rd one for in app navigation/bottombar navigation

**RootNavGraph**

```
    @Composable
fun RootNavGraph(tokenManager: TokenManager,navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController = navController,route=Graph.ROOT, startDestination = Graph.AUTH){
        authNavGraph(tokenManager = tokenManager, navController = navController )
        composable(route=Graph.HOME){
            HomeScreen()
        }
    }
}

object Graph{
    const val ROOT="root_graph"
    const val AUTH="auth_graph"
    const val HOME="main_graph"
}
```

**AuthNavGraph**

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.authNavGraph(tokenManager: TokenManager, navController: NavHostController) {
    navigation(route=Graph.AUTH, startDestination = AuthScreen.SplashScreen.route){
        composable(AuthScreen.SplashScreen.route){
            SplashScreen(navController,tokenManager)
        }
        navigation(
            route= AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.route,
            startDestination = AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.RegisterScreen.route
        ){
            composable(AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.RegisterScreen.route){
                RegisterScreen(
                    tokenManager,
                    onClick={
                        navController.popBackStack()
                        navController.navigate(Graph.HOME)
                    },
                    onLogin={
                        navController.navigate(AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.LoginScreen.route)
                    }
                )
            }
            composable(AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.LoginScreen.route){
                LoginScreen(
                    tokenManager,
                    onClick={
                        navController.popBackStack()
                        navController.navigate(Graph.HOME)
                    },
                    onRegister={
                        navController.navigate(AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.RegisterScreen.route)
                    },
                    onForgot={
                        navController.navigate(AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.ForgotPassword.route)
                    }
                )
            }
            navigation(
                route= AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.ForgotPassword.route,
                startDestination =AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.ForgotPassword.ForgotPasswordScreen.route
            ){
                composable(AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.ForgotPassword.ForgotPasswordScreen.route){
                    ForgotPasswordScreen(navController)
                }
                composable(
                    AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.ForgotPassword.ResetPasswordScreen.route,arguments=
                    listOf(navArgument("email"){type= NavType.StringType})
                ){
                    val email=it.arguments?.getString("email")
                    Log.d("EMAIL",email!!)
                    ResetPasswordScreen(navController, email)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeNavGraph**

```
@Composable
fun HomeNavGraph(navController:NavHostController, paddingValues: PaddingValues) {
    val sharedViewModel:SharedViewModel= viewModel()
    NavHost(navController = navController, route = Graph.HOME, startDestination =BottomBarItem.Main.route ){

        composable(route=BottomBarItem.Main.route){
            MainScreen(navController,sharedViewModel)
        }

        composable(route=BottomBarItem.Profile.route){
            ProfileScreen(navController)
        }

        composable(route=BottomBarItem.Cart.route){
            CartScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(route="details"){
            DetailScreen(sharedViewModel,navController)
        }

        composable(route="catProducts/{id}",arguments=
        listOf(navArgument("id"){type= NavType.StringType})){
            val id=it.arguments?.getString("id")!!
            CatProducts(id,navController,sharedViewModel)
        }

        composable(route="checkout"){
            CheckoutScreen()
        }

        composable(route="orders"){
            OrderScreen(navController)
        }
        composable(route="orderDetail/{id}",arguments=listOf(navArgument("id"){type= NavType.StringType})){
            val orderId=it.arguments?.getString("id")!!
            OrderDetailScreen(orderId)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to navigate to LoginScreen from ProfileScren
When ever I try `navController.navigate(AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.LoginScreen.route)`

I get this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/login } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0xd750ce95) route=main_graph startDestination={Destination(0x78d845ec) route=home}`

How can I resolve it? please help!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the HomeNavGraph with

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.HomeNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController, 
    paddingValues: PaddingValues
) {
    val sharedViewModel:SharedViewModel= viewModel()
    navigation(route = Graph.HOME, startDestination = BottomBarItem.Main.route){
        ...
    }
}
```

and add the HomeNavGraph to the RootNavGraph

```
fun RootNavGraph(tokenManager: TokenManager,navController: NavHostController) {
NavHost(navController = navController,route=Graph.ROOT, startDestination = Graph.AUTH){
    authNavGraph(tokenManager = tokenManager, navController = navController )
    HomeNavGraph(navController, paddingValues)
    composable(route=Graph.HOME){
        HomeScreen()
    }
}
```

}